# How to force single threaded execution?

Tags: linux, gdb, openmp

I want to execute a program only in a single thread. Naturally, this program uses the OpenMP library to run multi-threaded, but for some debugging purpose, I want to have multi-threading disabled.

Is there an option in `gdb` or maybe on `ld.so`-level to dynamically link only to a dummy OpenMP-library that gives reasonable behaviour to omp calls (e.g. `omp_get_num_threads` will always return `1`) but doesn't start more than one thread?

Comment: Your OpenMP implementation may include an OpenMP library with serial stubs, as Intel's does.  If you want an answer which is implementation independent, stick with the environment variables and function calls.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How about setting OMP_NUM_THREADS=1 at runtime? You may also want to set OMP_THREAD_LIMIT=1 for good measure.

Comment: Yes, that's what environment variables are for.

Comment: However, be aware that there are many codes which effectively ignore the envirable by hard-wiring in "omp_set_num_threads(4)" (or similar), on the grounds that "I have four cores in my machine". You may be able to divine that I think this is an awful idea, but, unfortunately, it remains common.

Comment: This is why I suggested OMP_THREAD_LIMIT=1 in addition to OMP_NUM_THREADS, as I think it should reduce even those hard-wired cases down to 1.